# How to add css sibling property that's less than 4 properties with emmet?

Tags: html, css, emmet

With emmet in CSS, you can add multiple siblings at the same time like this:

```css
body {
  /* df+jcc+aic+mh100vh this will output below*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

But if it's less than four properties it won't work, like:

```css
body {
  /* df+jcc+aic this emmet syntax won't work*/
}
```

In HTML, it's possible to do this `input+button`, but in CSS it won't work if it's less than 4 properties.

So is it possible to get emmet work in CSS like this:

```css
body {
  /* df+jcc+aic I wanted it to output like below */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

edit: **I just realized that you can actually add multiple siblings that's less than 4 properties in CSS with emmet.**

This works:

```css
body {
  /* df+mo this works */
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
```

but `df+jcc+aic` for some reason won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily setup your custom emmet try this link

code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_using-custom-emmet-snippets

Comment: This worked, but this doesn't actually answer my question. With this, I will have to define every snippet.

Comment: Alright, I just realized that you can actually add multiple siblings that's less than 4 properties with emmet. `df+m0` worked lol, but when you pair the `df` with `jcc+aic` it won't work.